# css not displaying after .animate has run

Tags: jquery, css

ok so I have this, I have the css set to display none but when the .animate runs I want it to then display inline a list, can anyone help point out whats wrong ? Thanks Tim

```
    $('.settings-button').click(
        function () {
            $('.settings-box').animate({ height: 150 }, 750, function () {

                $('.Settings-list').css({
                    'Display': 'inline',
                });
            });
        }
    );
```

Comment: what do you mean by then, after the animate or while?

Comment: once the animate has finish I want a list to switch from display none to display inline

Comment: It should work what is not working?

Comment: thats what I was thinking, really have no idea why its not :( its just not replaceing the css

Comment: Hmm, ok, comment on this please should be odd but remove the trailing `,` from the css :D

Comment: This because of the capital letter ! 'Display' should be 'display' !!!

Comment: @Guillaume *All CSS syntax is case-insensitive within the ASCII range (i.e., [a-z] and [A-Z] are equivalent)...* http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#characters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only reason this isnt working is because your not auto hiding the div tag when loading with

```
 $('.Settings-list').hide()
```

as show above, in other comments.

along with the case with css is sensitive `'display'` not `'Display'`

after that what you have is perfectly fine.

full code

```
   $('.Settings-list').hide()
        $('.settings-button').click(
            function () {
                $('.settings-box').animate({ height: 150 }, 750, function () {
                    $('.Settings-list').css({
                        'display': 'inline',                        
                    });
                });
            }
        );
```

Thanks Alan

Comment: *All CSS syntax is case-insensitive within the ASCII range (i.e., [a-z] and [A-Z] are equivalent)...* http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#characters

Answer (score 1):

Errors in your code :-

1)- `Display` should be `display` - **small** `d`

2)-used `,` here `'Display': 'inline',`. Not needed if applying only one `style`

```
$('.settings-button').click(
    function () {
        $('.settings-box').animate({ height: 150 }, 750, function () {

            $('.Settings-list').css({'display': 'inline'});
        });
    }
);
```

Comment: *All CSS syntax is case-insensitive within the ASCII range (i.e., [a-z] and [A-Z] are equivalent)...* http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#characters

Comment: I tried on my end .Setting the css keeping `d` as capital .It didn't worked .

Comment: Try this http://jsfiddle.net/ojuhugsh/1/ and then make capital `D` to small `d` .You will find that it works .

Comment: Then JSFIDDLE does not comply to rules!

Comment: jQuery does not comply to rules

Comment: yes , that's what i was thinking of .It's the jQuery not complying to the `CSS`rules .

Comment: yeah, that's very strange, all they have to do is place the user input inline, tzzz

Answer (score 0):

use this in your CSS:

```
.Settings-list{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

use this in script

```
$(".Settings-list").hide();
$('.settings-button').click(
    function () {
        $('.settings-box').animate({ height: 150 }, 750, function () {

           $(".Settings-list").show();             

        });
    }
);
```

Comment: pretty sure he meant inline-block

Answer (score 0):

You can remove your `display: none;` and try this

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
$('.Settings-list').hide();

$('.settings-button').click(
        function () {
            $('.Settings-list').show('slow');
            $('.settings-box').animate({ height: 150 }, 750, function () {

                $('.Settings-list').css({
                    'Display': 'inline',
                });
            });
        }
    );
});
```

Comment: if i remove the display none the the css loads the list to start with and then wont go away

Comment: `$('.Settings-list').hide();` should hide it until the `.settings-button` is clicked.

Comment: thanks I might need add a fader to it so it isnt just jumpping out ont he screen but thats good :)

Comment: mark as correct if you're happy with the answer. thanks.

Comment: its not really pointed out the display Display issue, like other have thus my 1up but not correct answer

Answer (score 0):

Jquery .css is case sensitive. Change 'Display' to 'display'.

Comment: Yeah sorry, answers was not refressed on page. I vote the other answer.

Comment: I mean *All CSS syntax is case-insensitive within the ASCII range (i.e., [a-z] and [A-Z] are equivalent)...* http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#characters

Comment: I belive you but here you use a jQuery method to implement the CSS code.

Comment: Test it here http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_css_getcolor